# Uniform Continuity of a Sequence of Functions with a Piece-Wise Defined Limit

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence of functions
$$h_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^n}$$
over the domain $[0,\infty)$.

I found its pointwise limit to be

$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
x & \text{ if } 0\leq x<1\text{,}  \\ 
1/2 & \text{ if } x=1\text{,}  \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x>1\text{.} 
\end{cases}$$

But I have a "gut-feeling" that the function may not be uniformly continuous over that interval (because it is piece-wise defined), so I am now trying to find a smaller set for which it is:

I naturally went with the choice of $(0,1)$, but then
$$\left|h_n(x)-h(x)\right|=\left|\frac{x}{1+x^n}-x\right|=\frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x^n}<x<\epsilon,$$

which does not provide the necessary information I need to conclude that the function is uniformly continuous over that interval.

Do you guys have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: $h$ is not continuous, so in particular this function cannot be uniformly continuous.

Comment: But could it be shown that it is uniformly continuous over a smaller set?

Comment: $h$ is continuous on $[0,1)$ and $(1,+\infty)$ (uniformly in the second set). What is exactly the question?

Comment: I just needed to find a set over which the sequence converges uniformly. :) I will try the set $(1, \infty)$, as you suggested.

Comment: isn't $h$ also uniformly continuous on $[0,1)$. Pf: let $\varepsilon=\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|<\delta=\varepsilon$

Comment: This is what I now have: Over the set $(1,\infty)$, we see that $|h_n(x)-h(x)|=|x/(1+x^n)-0|=x/(1+x^n)<1/2$. Is this sufficient to show that the function converges uniformly over that interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

As noted in the comments,  $(h_n)$ does not converge uniformly on $[1,\infty)$ or on $[0,1]$, since its limit function is discontinuous on those intervals.

By considering the values $x_n=1-{1\over n}$, you should be able to show that $(h_n)$ does not converge uniformly on the interval $[0,1)$ (compute $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} h_n(x_n)$). By considering $x_n=1+{1\over n}$, you should be able to show that $(h_n)$ does not converge uniformly on the interval $(1,\infty)$ (note this would also verify the results of the preceeding paragraph).

But, consider what type of convergence you have on a set of the form $[0,1-\epsilon]$ or $[1+\epsilon,\infty)$ for a fixed $\epsilon>0$. Here, use the inequalities
$$
\Bigl| {x\over 1+x^n} -x  \Bigr|=\Bigl| {x^{n+1}\over 1+x^n}\Bigr|\le x^{n+1},
$$
for the $[0,1-\epsilon]$ case; and
$$
\Bigl| {x\over 1+x^n}   \Bigr|\le\Bigl| {x \over  x^n}\Bigr|={1\over x^{n-1}},
$$
for the $[1+\epsilon,\infty)$ case.

---

Looking at the  graphs of the $h_n$ should help:

[image]

Above are plotted $\color{darkred}{h_2}$, $\color{darkslateblue}{h_4}$, $\color{olivedrab}{h_{10}}$, $\color{salmon}{h_{40}}$, $\color{cyan}{h_{60}}$, $\color{yellow}{h_{100}}$,
and  $\color{pink}{h_{1000}}$ (the yellow is $h_{100}$; it's barely readable on my monitor).